# How do I prevent jsp scriptlet from execution?

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

when i run the program, both statements inside the condition got executed

```
<script>
    if (true) {
       <%System.out.println("true");%>
    } else {
       <%System.out.println("false");%>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java and JavaScript are completely different—their similar names notwithstanding.  They have as much in common as the words “pain” and “painting”.

- JSP code is executed in the server, before the user ever receives the page.
- JavaScript is executed on the end user’s computer, after the server has executed all of its code, assembled the page, and delivered it to the user’s browser.

The server doesn’t process any JSP content other than JSP tags, or known tag libraries like JSTL.  That `<script>` element and its content is simply added to the final page as is, without ever being interpreted or executed.

In other words, `if (true)` means nothing to the server.  It ignores the JavaScript, and only executes the `<%`…`%>` parts.

When the page is finally delivered to the browser, the source will contain this:

```
<script>
    if (true) {

    } else {

    }
</script>
```

…because the JavaScript was not processed in any way on the server side.  JavaScript in HTML pages runs in browsers, not on the server.

You probably want something like this:

```
<%
    if (true) {
       System.out.println("true");
    } else {
       System.out.println("false");
    }
%>
```

Not that the above does not need to be in a `<script>` element, and in fact it would not make sense to put it in one—because `<script>` contains JavaScript and this is server side Java code, not JavaScript.